# How can I avoid multiple calls to `map_err` in a chain of Results?

Tags: rust, error-handling

I am working with some code that uses the [libgit2 bindings for Rust](https://docs.rs/git2/latest/git2/) to perform operations on a Git repository.

I have a section of code that transforms a "commitish" reference (something that either is a commit or ultimately references a commit, like a tag) that currently looks like this:

```
let mut target_commit = target_object
    .peel(git2::ObjectType::Commit)
    .map_err(|_| anyhow!("Target `{commitish}` cannot be evaluated as a commit"))?
    .into_commit()
    .map_err(|_| anyhow!("Target `{commitish}` cannot be evaluated as a commit"))?;
```

I'd like to avoid having two identical calls to `map_err` in that
chain. Based on the description of the `and_then` combinator

> Calls `op` if the result is `Ok`, otherwise returns the `Err` value of self.

I thought maybe this would work:

```
let mut target_commit = target_object
    .peel(git2::ObjectType::Commit)
    .and_then(|c| c.into_commit())
    .map_err(|_| anyhow!("Target `{commitish}` cannot be evaluated as a commit"))?;
```

But that fails with:

```
106 |             .and_then(|c| c.into_commit())
    |                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `git2::Error`, found struct `git2::Object`
```

What's the correct way to simplify this expression?

Comment: Remember `map_err` can take a `fn` as an argument, so you should be able to define `fn target_cannot(_e: impl Error)` and then `map_err(target_cannot)`, at least presuming you can make the argument sufficiently generic.

Comment: @tadman: That is nice, but  [`into_commit()`](https://docs.rs/git2/latest/git2/struct.Object.html#method.into_commit) returns the original object in case of error, so it does not `impl Error`, I think. A fully generic `fn target_cannot<E>(_: E) { anyhow!(...) }` should work, although I usually prefer `let target_cannot = |_| anyhow!(...);` because it is shorter, more like the original code and can capture local variables for context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplification could mean multiple things. One way to simplify is to remove the duplication of the `anyhow!()` invocation.

Since you don't actually use the error information, you can use [`Result::ok`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.ok) to discard the error information by converting the `Result<T, E>` to `Option<T>`, then use [`Option::ok_or_else`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.ok_or_else) at the end of a chain to turn the final `Option` back into a `Result`.

```
let mut target_commit = target_object
    .peel(git2::ObjectType::Commit).ok()
    .and_then(|c| c.into_commit().ok())
    .ok_or_else(|| anyhow!("Target `{commitish}` cannot be evaluated as a commit"))?;
```

Comment: Just to make sure I follow: Calling `.ok()` gets us an `Option`, which will either wrap the result value from the previous method call or will be `None` in the event of an error. `ok_or_else` transforms an `Option` into a `Result`; if it's an `Err` then that is propagated upwards by `?`, otherwise it's unwrapped and the value is assigned to `target_commit`?

Comment: @larsks Yep, that's it.